# Ordenar del mas pequeño al mas grande MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqlprocedure

Resulta que estamos viendo clases los procedure y las funciones pero no me sale ordenados todos los que deseo el objetivo es recibir 3 numeros por parametros y luego devolverlo ordenados.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mayor $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mayor(IN n1 INT, IN n2 INT, IN n3 INT)
BEGIN

    IF N1 < N2 THEN 

        IF N2 < N3 THEN

            SELECT N1 AS PEQUEÑO, N2 AS MEDIANO, N3 AS GRANDE;

        ELSEIF N3 < N2 THEN

            SELECT N1 AS PEQUEÑO, N3 AS MEDIANO, N2 AS GRANDE;

        END IF;

    ELSEIF N2 < N1 THEN

        IF N1 < N3 THEN

            SELECT N2 AS PEQUEÑO, N1 AS MEDIANO, N3 AS GRANDE;

        ELSEIF N3 < N1 THEN 

            SELECT N2 AS PEQUEÑO, N3 AS MEDIANO, N1 AS GRANDE;

        END IF;

    ELSEIF N3 < N1 THEN

        IF N1 < N2 THEN

            SELECT N3 AS PEQUEÑO, N1 AS MEDIANO, N2 AS GRANDE;

        ELSEIF N2 < N1 THEN

            SELECT N3,N2,N1;

        END IF;

    END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Algo de mi lógica del programa pero no encuentro el que. Me falla cuando N3 es el mas pequeño.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo una captura de lo que me devuelve

Comment: Los problemas de lógica del programa se solucionan pensando. Por ejemplo, céntrate en tu código en el primer `IF N1 < N2`. Si te das cuenta, te falta comprobar si N3 es menor que N1. Estás asumiendo que N1 es el más pequeño simplemente porque es menor que N2. Piensa una buena lógica (un buen algoritmo), y luego pásalo a código.

Comment: vale muchas gracias lo estoy mirando y voy a probar lo que has dicho

Comment: era eso muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te han comentado, te faltan comprobaciones. Te paso tres posibles soluciones:

Algo parecido a la burbuja:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mayor(IN n1 INT, IN n2 INT, IN n3 INT)
BEGIN
  declare aux int;
  WHILE n1>n2 OR n2>n3 DO
    if n1>n2 THEN 
      SET aux=n1;
      SET n1=n2;
      SET n2=aux;
    end IF;
    if n2>n3 THEN 
      SET aux=n2;
      SET n2=n3;
      SET n3=aux;
    end IF;
  end WHILE;
  SELECT n1 PEQUEÑO, n2 MEDIANO, n3 GRANDE;
END
```

Haciendo uso de una tabla temporal:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mayor(IN n1 INT, IN n2 INT, IN n3 INT)
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nums(
    id_num int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    num int                            
  );
  INSERT INTO nums (num) VALUES (n1),(n2),(n3);
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(num ORDER BY num)
    FROM nums;
END
```

Y usando funciones de MySQL para localizar máximos y mínimos:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mayor(IN n1 INT, IN n2 INT, IN n3 INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE aux1,aux2,aux3 int;
  SET aux3=GREATEST(n1,n2,n3);
  SET aux1=LEAST(n1,n2,n3);
  if n1 NOT IN (aux1,aux3) then set aux2=n1; END IF;
  if n2 NOT IN (aux1,aux3) then set aux2=n2; END IF;
  if n3 NOT IN (aux1,aux3) then set aux2=n3; END IF;
  SELECT aux1 PEQUEÑO, aux2 MEDIANO, aux3 GRANDE;
END
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero ya lo he solucionado por su comentario

Comment: Genial, pero no te quedes ahí, continúa mejorando tu técnica de programación haciendo un código cada vez más legible y escalable... Leer código de otros programadores ayuda y acabo de darte tres perspectivas diferentes a la tuya, con sus errores y aciertos, espero que te resulten útiles a ti y a la comunidad de SO

Comment: vale muchas gracias el profesor lo que quiere es que nos hagamos con la sintaxis para poder realizar ejercicios mas grandes pero de todo modo ire mejorando

Answer (score 1):

El problema estaba en que me faltaba mas comprobaciones. Gracias a José Carlos PHP

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mayor $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mayor(IN n1 INT, IN n2 INT, IN n3 INT)
BEGIN

    IF N1 < N2 AND N1 < N3 THEN 

        IF N2 < N3 THEN

            SELECT N1 AS PEQUEÑO, N2 AS MEDIANO, N3 AS GRANDE;

        ELSEIF N3 < N2 THEN

            SELECT N1 AS PEQUEÑO, N3 AS MEDIANO, N2 AS GRANDE;

        END IF;

    END IF;

    IF N2 < N1 AND N2 < N3 THEN

        IF N1 < N3 THEN

            SELECT N2 AS PEQUEÑO, N1 AS MEDIANO, N3 AS GRANDE;

        ELSEIF N3 < N1 THEN 

            SELECT N2 AS PEQUEÑO, N3 AS MEDIANO, N1 AS GRANDE;

        END IF;

    END IF;

    IF N3 < N1 AND N3 < N2 THEN

        IF N1 < N2 THEN

            SELECT N3 AS PEQUEÑO, N1 AS MEDIANO, N2 AS GRANDE;

        ELSEIF N2 < N1 THEN

            SELECT N3 AS PEQUEÑO, N2 AS MEDIANO, N1 AS GRANDE;

        END IF;

    END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```